# Google calendar API to create event like Goals in android

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, google-calendar-api

Is there any API or library to create a calendar event like goals in Android.
Google Calendar uses Artificial Intelligence for Creating goals and rescheduling that events, I want to Implement same thing in my app.
Done some research but couldn't find any library.

Any help will be appreciated,  thank you

Comment: anything new in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'm coming a bit late to the party, but I strongly suggest you look at Google's Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). It features a nice API for creating events, and you can set the scripts to run on triggers such as calendar modification, which kind of suits your needs, as goals need to be rescheduled whenever they conflict with an existing event.
Using artificial intelligence might be a little tricky with GAS, and there's no library that I know of that could do that tough.